# $f$ continuous, $g$ holomorphic with $g'(z) \neq 0 $, $g(f(z))=z$ $=> f$ holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $U,V\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open, $f: U \to V$ continuous, $g\in H(V)$  with $g'(z)\neq0$ and $g(f(z))=z$. Then
>   \begin{aligned} f \in H(U)\end{aligned}

My idea was to write:

$1=\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{z-z_0}=\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{f(z)-f(z_0)}*\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$

Is it true, that since $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{f(z)-f(z_0)}$ exists and is unequal $0$, also $\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ has to exist?

I think it does, but I am not sure and I cannot think of a proper way to proof this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

More rigorously, since the limit exist, we could write

$$\begin{align} 1 &= \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{f(z)-f(z_0)}\cdot \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\\
&= \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{f(z)-f(z_0)}\cdot \lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} \qquad (\star)\\
&= \lim_{w \to w_0} \frac{g(w)-g(w_0)}{w-w_0}\cdot \lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0},\end{align}$$

where $w_0 := f(z_0)$.

Note that the second equality $(\star)$ is NOT the multiplication rule for limit! (Because we don't know if $\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists or not.) Instead, the proposition we use is the following:

> If $\lim_{z \to z_0} f_1(z)f_2(z)$ and $\lim_{z \to z_0} f_1(z)$ both exists and $\lim_{z \to z_0} f_1(z) \neq 0$,then $$\lim_{z \to z_0} f_1(z)f_2(z) = \lim_{z \to z_0} f_1(z) \cdot \lim_{z \to z_0} f_2(z)$$

The proof is not hard (by using $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.)

For the last equality, it holds since $f(z) \to f(z_0)$ as $z \to z_0$ by continuity of $f$.

Therefore $\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists if $\lim_{w \to w_0} \frac{g(w)-g(w_0)}{w-w_0}$ exists and is unequal to $0$.

Comment: Ah, I see:

$\frac{1}{\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{f(z)-f(z_0)}}=\frac{\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{f(z)-f(z_0)}*\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}}{\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{f(z)-f(z_0)}}=^1\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{\frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{f(z)-f(z_0)}*\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}}{\frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_0))}{f(z)-f(z_0)}}=\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} $ And in $1$ I used the normal formula for the fraction of two existing limes. Thanks, you gave me the small push I needed :)

Comment: I'm not so sure this argument goes through. Consider that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x = 0$. It doesn't follow that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ exists. On the contrary, that limit doesn't exist. We can only split limits across products if we know that the limit of each term exists.

Comment: Yes, but in your case $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}=0$. In general the formula $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)}{\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)}$ holds whenever $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) \neq 0$

Comment: The limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ does not exist. The formula $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)}{\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)}$ is only valid when $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x  \to 0} g(x)$ exists and is nonzero.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake there, the limit of 1 over x as x goes to 0 doesn't exist. As you said $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ have to exist. But this is the case here. The numarator on the left hand side of $=^1$ is equal to 1 and the denominator is equal go $g'(f(z_0))$ which is unequal 0.

Comment: Yes, the multiplication rule for limit says that  $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$ holds when $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ both exist, but I think it is also true when $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ both exists AND $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) \neq 0$. The proof of it needs an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument though.

Comment: I added some notes about this in the answer. Thank @Charles Hudgins for pointing that out, it is indeed a common mistake.